# creating a binary search tree struct and initializing it properly in C

Tags: c

So i'm trying to create a binary search tree in C but im a little bit confused and am running into issues.
This is what my structures look like:

```
typedef struct {
    void* item;
    struct Node** nodes;
}Node;

typedef struct{
    Node* tree_root; 
    int depth; 
    int item_size; 
} BST;
```

So in this case instead of having a left and right node initialized for the tree, I just have a '2D' array `Nodes** nodes` where `nodes[0]` is my left node on the tree and `nodes[1]` is my right node on the tree. I think I'm not properly initializing it because everytime I try to insert an item into the tree I get a `sgmentation fault(core dumped)` as an error. Heres how I create a node and initialize the tree:
// Create node containing item, return reference of it.

```
Node* createNode(void* item){
        Node *new_node;

    if ((new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    new_node->item = item;
    new_node->nodes[0] = NULL;
    new_node->nodes[1] = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Initializes the fields on the BST. Returns nothing.
void initBinaryTree(BST* tree, int item_size){
Node* root = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* left = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* right = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

tree->tree_root = root;
tree->tree_root->nodes[0] = left;
tree->tree_root->nodes[1] = right;
tree->item_size = item_size;
tree->depth = 0;

}
```

So im just trying to create the memory space for the nodes so that I can put stuff in there, im assuming the only reason I cant insert anything is because, i think, somewhere here I didnt do something right. So I was wondering if you guys could give me any advice on what I am or could potentially be doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here is my insertItem function that I use to try and insert stuff into the tree if anyone is curious: https://pastebin.com/5RYiSdBY

Comment: There are typos in `initBinaryTree`. The `root` is allocated multiple times. And `root->nodes` is never initialised so it cannot be dereferenced with `nodes[0]`. Need something like: `root->nodes = calloc(2, sizeof(node));`. Note, you should not allocate nodes for left and right when the node is first created. It should only be done when a child is added so that `NULL` can be used to check for the end of the sub-tree.

Comment: You can simplify your malloc calls: `Node* root = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

Answer (score 3):

You allocate a `Node`, but you never allocate space for the `nodes` member to point to.

For example, when you access `new_node->nodes[0]` you're dereferenceing the `nodes` member to access a pointer in an array, but there is no array because `nodes` doesn't point to anything.

Change your `Node` definition to:

```
typedef struct {
    void* item;
    struct Node *nodes[2];
}Node;
```

To make `nodes` an array so you don't have to allocate space for it.

You also have typos in `initBinaryTree`:

```
Node* root = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* left = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* right = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

This should be:

```
Node* root = NULL;
root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* left = NULL;
left = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* right = NULL;
right = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

But... you shouldn't create blank nodes when you initialize the tree.  The `root` member should start as `NULL`, then you add nodes as you go.

Comment: So I shouldnt even try to initialize the left and the right node in my init Function? Should initialize the root?

Comment: @Aviera00 You would set `tree->tree_root` to `NULL`.  Then the first node you add becomes the root node.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. So I did this and I'm still getting the Segmentation Fault(core dump) error. im assuming that my createNode method is incorrect? then, so I tried adding this line to it `new_node->nodes = calloc(2, sizeof(Node));` I took it from another comment above to compensate for the `struct Node *nodes[2];` you recommended. It didnt work either is there something else that can be causing the error?

Comment: @Aviera00 You're probably doing something else wrong in your code.  Start by running it through valgrind, which will tell you where you may be mismanaging memory.